# mongodb closest string match lookup

Tags: mongodb, query-string

Is there any functionality in mongo to retrieve closest string match lookups.
For example,
Entries in the database are like:

- title: "bananashake"
- title: "bananasweet"
- title: "bananaturl"
- and so forth...

And suppose the user enters some text like "bananasweetest". Is there any way I could get bananasweet as the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Mongodb `v2.4`, you can create a Fulltext index to search through your data by creating an index

`db.reviews.ensureIndex( { comments: "text" } )`

[Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: I don't think the @Sushant is looking for full text search.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel he might not be, however it is a good solution to searching for text fields in databases

Comment: But the question is asking for an entirely different functionality. Isn't it?

Comment: @RoyToledo in 2013 it wasn't, the point isn't `ensureIndex` but to create a full text search index.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly looking for fulltext functionality which is not available in MongoDB. Look into Solr or ElasticSearch - outside the scope of MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you're looking for, you may be able to do it with a regex query: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions

Comment: Regular expressions are not suitable here -1

Comment: @AndreasJung That's right. RegExs are somehow exact.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree that Solr and ElasticSearch are good alternatives. You might also take the time to vote on this server issue in Jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-380